# Linear congruence solution confusion

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Why does: $4x \equiv 2 \bmod 6  $ have the solutions:

$x \equiv 2 \bmod 6  $    **AND**   $x \equiv 5 \bmod 6  $

I understand why $x \equiv 2 \bmod 6  $ as: $4 \cdot 2 = 8$ which is $2 + (1 \cdot 6)$ :.  $x \equiv 2 \bmod 6  $ but not sure why the second.

Comment: $6$ divides $4*5-2=18$

Comment: Where does the 5 come from? Apologies if this is pretty basic, but I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the solutions of $$2x\equiv 1\ (\ mod \ 3\ )$$

Each solution of this equation is also a solution of the given equation and the answer
 is $x\equiv 2\ (\ mod\ 3\ )$, which gives the solutions $2,5,8,11...$

So, modulo $6$, the solutions are $2$ and $5$.

Comment: I see where I have gone wrong. Thank you!